# What is the name of this bracket for the soil vent?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

I need to buy a new bracket as the one holding the external vent is broken and pipe is wobbling.

What is it called so I can search for a new one? It's about 12cm external diameter.

[image: Bracket]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after is a "[pipe wall strap](https://www.google.com/search?q=pipe+wall+strap&tbm=isch)".

Comment: I presume it's one for a Ø110mm/4'' Soil Pipe. My external diameter measurement was 120mm but i believe that inside diameter is what counts for a pipe. So about 5mm on each wall would roughly add up?!? Apologies if this should be new distinct question!

Comment: Yes, straps would usually be sized for nominal pipe diameter, not actual outer diameter.